# How is interest on shorted shares calculated?

Tags: stocks, shares

Is the formula below correct?

[Shares shorted * price sold] * [annual interest rate / 360 * # of days borrowed] = interest charged

Based on the formula, it doesn't seem like interest is compounded.

Answer (score 2):

The formula is:

- (Borrow rate) x (market value of the security)/365

It's a borrow fee rather than interest.  The borrow rate and the price of the security can fluctuate daily.  It is charged for holding a short position overnight and is calculated daily.  Typically, it accrues and is debited monthly.